# node--page.tpl.php not detected in Omega subtheme

Tags: theming

I created a `sites/all/themes/mySubtheme/templates/node--page.tpl.php` in a Omega subtheme.

I cleared all caches but it is not detected at all.

I even try with `sites/all/themes/mySubtheme/templates/node.tpl.php` to theme all nodes, just in case that I would have a typo error, but not working.

The base of my subtheme is omega:

```
base theme = 'omega'
```

I've also made sure that the tpl.php file exist in:

`sites/all/themes/omega/templates/node--page.tpl.php`

`sites/all/themes/starterkits/omega-html5/templates/node--page.tpl.php`

`sites/all/themes/starterkits/omega-xhtml/templates/node--page.tpl.php`

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to theme pages with nodes or a node type named `page` ?

Comment: I have to theme node type called 'page'

Comment: Your node templates look correct (from what i can see from finder tree). You can check available variables (to the node.tpl.php) using a theme preprocess function. Install Devel and http://codepad.org/74cXLdSE

Answer (score 2):

No node override templates will be repected unless the *original* node.tpl.php file is also in your theme folder.

Copy the standard template file to node.tpl.php in your theme, clear the caches, and you should be good to go.

Comment: @clive: I already copied the file to every theme folder, pls take a look at the 3 last lines of my question.

Comment: The last 3 lines of your question don't mention the node.tpl.php file, they mention node--page.tpl.php...please read the last 4 lines of my answer, especially the bit in italics ;)

Comment: I did that, but not working, look a the capture I added at the bottom of the question

Comment: hi @chefnelone, did you find a way to solve this issue? Apparently Omega doesn't node.tp.php. I deleted all files you have pointed in your capture, and nodes are still correctly displayed after cache flush.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the entire templates folder and paste it inside your subtheme template folder.Now try to create a new node--Type.tpl.php . This should work.